# Identity transformation translates image in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transformation

while transforming images with PIL (1.1.7, Portable Python 2.7.5.1, Windows 7) I stumbled upon a behaviour I find quite strange. When transforming an image with an identity matrix (1,0,0,0,1,0,0) I expect the resulting image to be the exact input (as when using OpenCV). With filter=Image.NEAREST that holds true but not for Image.BILINEAR or Image.BICUBIC. The image is translated to the bottom right.

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
im = Image.new('L', (64, 64), 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.line((8,8, 32,8), fill=255)
draw.line((8,8, 8,32), fill=255)
im.save('out1.png')
im = im.transform((64, 64), Image.AFFINE, (1,0,0,0,1,0), Image.BICUBIC)
im.save('out2.png')
im = im.transform((64, 64), Image.AFFINE, (1,0,0,0,1,0), Image.BICUBIC)
im.save('out3.png')
im = im.transform((64, 64), Image.AFFINE, (1,0,0,0,1,0), Image.BICUBIC)
im.save('out4.png')
```

[image: out1.png]
[image: out2.png]
[image: out3.png]
[image: out4.png]

Is this intended (I was unable to find something about this in the docs.) or a bug worth reporting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With current versions of Pillow (I'm using ver. 5.0.0 right now) this seems to be fixed. :)